# flashing jelly bean(4.2.2) on nexus 5(hammerhead)

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, nexus-5

I am trying to flash jelly bean on Nexus 5 but didn't find any factory images , is it possible to flash the jelly bean(4.2.2) image generated by downloading & compiling the 4.2.2 AOSP source code

i tried running lunch command but didn't found the "aosp_hammerhead_userdebug" is there any other way to flash 4.2.2 on nexus 5

Answer (score 2):

Its because Nexus 5 not came with Jellybean. It was Kitkat. That is why you can't find Jellybean factory images for Nexus 5. You may try to flash custom Jellybean ROMs(4.2.2) for Nexus 5 if available.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid you cant because Nexus 5 shipped with kitkat and backward compatibility is not supported.